# flatten json with multiple lists

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, snowflake-schema

I have a json file in S3 that looks like this. There are lists within the main list and each list can contain multiple dictionaries:

```
[
    [
        {"cmsId": "63db9878d1",
            "documentType": "video"}, 
         {"cmsId": "ddd1",
            "documentType": "article"}
],
[   {"cmsId": "63db",
            "documentType": "blog"}, 
         {"cmsId": "63db987",
            "documentType": "article"}
]]
```

How can I use SNOWFLAKE sql to parse the cmsIds and documenttypes (only the root level items)?

I was trying this but it keeps running forever with no output:

```
select
              *,
               metadata$filename                                as file_name,
               to_timestamp_ntz(current_timestamp())            as load_date
        from
        @STG.S3/lean/incoming (FILE_FORMAT => STG.JSON_NO_OUTER_IVW     , pattern=>'.*20230526_ids.gz' ) t
      ,TABLE(FLATTEN(input => t.$1 , outer => false   ))
```

file format ddl:

```
{
   "TYPE":"JSON",
   "FILE_EXTENSION":null,
   "DATE_FORMAT":"AUTO",
   "TIME_FORMAT":"AUTO",
   "TIMESTAMP_FORMAT":"AUTO",
   "BINARY_FORMAT":"HEX",
   "TRIM_SPACE":false,
   "NULL_IF":[
      
   ],
   "COMPRESSION":"AUTO",
   "ENABLE_OCTAL":false,
   "ALLOW_DUPLICATE":false,
   "STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY":true,
   "STRIP_NULL_VALUES":true,
   "IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS":false,
   "REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS":false,
   "SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK":true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have loaded data already, You can flatten stage by stage in Sub Queries.

```
select
    l2.VALUE:"cmsId" :: string,
    l2.VALUE:"documentType"  :: string
from (
    select
        l1.VALUE
    from (
        select
            parse_json('[
                [
                    {"cmsId": "63db9878d1",
                        "documentType": "video"}, 
                    {"cmsId": "ddd1",
                        "documentType": "article"}
            ],
            [   {"cmsId": "63db",
                        "documentType": "blog"}, 
                    {"cmsId": "63db987",
                        "documentType": "article"}
            ]
        ]')
    ) as t,
    lateral flatten (t.$1) as l1
) as t,
lateral flatten (t.VALUE) as l2
```

**Edit 1**
if it is not Loaded, You can tweek FILE_FORMAT object by setting `STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE`. this will eliminate First array and load data in two rows, You can later flatten and read data from second array.

**Edit 2**
Just in case if you loaded data into table with file_format having `STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY= TRUE`, follow query will help you to get desired results.

```
select
    l2.VALUE:"cmsId" :: string,
    l2.VALUE:"documentType"  :: string
from TABLE_NAME as t,
lateral flatten (t.VALUE) as l2
```

Comment: can you modify it according to an s3 load/?

Comment: tell me  about the DDL of the FILE_FORMAT object `STG.JSON_NO_OUTER_IVW`.

Comment: I updated it in the qs

Comment: I see you have set `STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE` this setting will convert first first array and return elements in separate rows. so you can now select query by using `lateral flatten` on your `variant` column and select extract results from VALUE field.

Comment: The fileformat I am using already has STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE. Maybe that's why your code works with the sample data but not with my s3 file directly.

Comment: Exactly, So now you don't need use the exact code, only the outer layer of code is enough, like I show in answer. If this helps mark it as answer.